# Problema de memoria "bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes)" a la hora de hacer un composer require

Tags: php, composer, librería

Hace ya varios dias estoy intentando instalar un paquete para laravel, que en los tutoriales funcionan. El problema surge que cuando yo intento hacer:

> C:\wamp64\www\tienda>composer require darryldecode/cart

Sale el siguiente error:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleWatchGraph.php on line 52
>
> Check https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-errors for more info on how to handle out of memory errors.

Ya intenté aumentar el tamaño de memoria de PHP y no funcionó. También intenté actualizar el composer y tampocó funcionó.
Necesito ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta agregar `COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1` antes de colocar tu paquete composer

para el paquete que intentas instalar seria:

```
COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer require darryldecode/cart
```